# Sunscreen protection, SPF, and amount applied: relationship?

Tags: optics, electromagnetic-radiation, everyday-life, reflection, absorption

In the article [How SPF Changes with How Much Sunscreen You Use](https://labmuffin.com/spf-changes-how-much-sunscreen-use/) (last updated Dec 29, 2017), the author says that insufficient sunscreen disturbingly decreases protection *exponentially*, in other words, that sunscreen application has *increasing* marginal utility:

> The amount used in the sunscreen studies to determine SPF is $2$ milligrams of sunscreen per centimetre of skin.
>
> On average, **people apply only a quarter to a half of the recommended amount**, and in most studies, it’s closer to $0.5$ mg/cm².
>
> In physics, you’d expect **protection** to **decrease exponentially with less sunscreen**. This is based on a relationship called the Beer-Lambert law, and is illustrated [as](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/9453080)
>
> [image]
>
> it’s the middle of the graph that’s disturbing.
>
> **Applying half the recommended amount of sunscreen cannot give more than SPF $\mathbf{10}$**, even with SPF $50$ sunscreen!
>
> by $0.5$ mg/cm², we’re below SPF $3$ for all products.

Now, intuitively, the initial layer of sunscreen makes a greater difference than any subsequent layer, that is, each layer of the recommended amount of sunscreen is less beneficial than the previous layer; does the theory *really* contradict this intuition?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. A sunscreen's **sun protection factor** (SPF) is defined as $$\frac{\text{minimal erythemal dose in sunscreen-protected skin}}{\text{minimal erythemal dose in non-sunscreen-protected skin}},$$ so its **transmittance** (transmitted percentage of the incident erythemal radiation) is $$T=\frac1{\text{SPF}}\times100\%.\tag1$$ [image]

   So, the sunscreen's **percentage protection** (filtered-out percentage of the incident erythemal radiation) is $$\left(1-\frac1{\text{SPF}}\right)\times100\%\tag2.$$ [image]
2. Let $s$ be a sunscreen's **intended SPF**, $x$ be the **applied
   fraction of its prescribed amount**, and $f(s,x)$ be its effective
   SPF.

   [Beer's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beer%E2%80%93Lambert_law)
   predicts that the sunscreen's **absorbance**
   $\left(\log_{10}\dfrac1{T(s,x)}\right)$ is directly proportional to $x.$
   So, $T(s,x)=e^{-k_sx}$ for some positive $k_s,$ so the sunscreen's transmittance decreases exponentially with $x.$ So, by formula
   $(1)$, $\large f(s,x)=e^{k_sx},$ so $f$ [increases exponentially](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4432035/21813) with $x.$ Thus,
   since $f(s,1)=s,$ the sunscreen's **effective SPF**
   is $$f(s,x)=s^x.\tag3$$ [image]

   So, by formula $(2)$, the sunscreen's **percentage protection**
   (filtered-out percentage of the incident erythemal radiation) is
   $$\left(1-\frac1{s^x}\right)\times100\%.\tag4$$ [image]
3. > > **In physics, you’d expect protection to decrease exponentially with less sunscreen.** This is based on a relationship called the Beer-Lambert law

   From formula $(3),$ Beer's Law predicts that *effective SPF*—not protection—decreases exponentially with less sunscreen.

   From formulae $(4),$ Beer's Law in fact predicts that **percentage protection increases with more sunscreen at a *decreasing* rate**, rather than exponentially.

   To be clear: effective SPF and percentage protection both increase with more sunscreen, but in different ways. The cited article is carelessly conflating these two concepts.

   > > According to this theoretical relationship, reducing the applied amount by one-quarter will already halve your sun protection if you’re using SPF 30 or above.
   > >
   > > Applying half the recommended amount of sunscreen (1.0 mg/cm²) cannot give more than SPF 10
   > >
   > > applying half the amount of sunscreen would give you less than half the protection.

   To be clear: from formula $(4),$ *applying half the prescribed
   amount of sunscreen actually confers **more than half** the intended
   amount of protection*, that is, it filters out more than half of what it would
   have with the full amount of sunscreen.

   For example, half the prescribed amount of an SPF $50$ (i.e., $98\%$
   percentage protection) sunscreen effectively attains SPF $7$ (i.e.,
   $86\%$ percentage protection); this is an efficacy decrease of only
   $12\%.$

   (Similarly, reducing the SPF from $50$ to $25$ decreases the
   efficacy by just $2\%,$ whereas reducing the SPF from $50$ to $2$
   decreases the efficacy by just $50\%;$ see graph $(2).)$
4. > > it seems like most sunscreens actually give a linear relationship,
   > > where half the sunscreen would actually give you around half the
   > > protection, like in the purple line below.
   > >
   > > One study even found that there was a logarithmic relationship like in
   > > the blue line on the graph, where half the sunscreen would actually
   > > give you more than half of the full protection!
   > >
   > > [image]
   > >
   > > In all of the studies, the protection achieved was much better than
   > > the amounts in the theoretical prediction.
   > >
   > > The proposed reasoning for why the Beer-Lambert law fails is because
   > > it assumes an even surface, when skin is actually uneven.

   The red curve ought to be translated upwards by one unit so that its vertical intercept becomes SPF $1;$ this is essentially graph $(3).$

   The purple curve (also to be translated upwards by one unit) gives a better prognosis than the red curve, which, as explained above, ***already*** says that half the sunscreen confers over half the protection.

   The purple curve does ***not*** say that the amount of radiation filtered out is [proportional to](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4331538/21813) the amount of sunscreen applied. (Remember, *SPF is neither proportional to nor even linearly related to percentage protection*; similarly, by formula $(1),$ SPF is inversely proportional to instead of linearly decreasing with transmittance.) In fact, for SPF $50,$ here are the corresponding quantities for the purple model:

   [image]

   The blue curve (also to be translated upwards by one unit) gives the most concave version of graph $(4).$ N.B. The blue curve—whether corrected or not—is ***not*** [logarithmic](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Logarithm.html) and, incidentally, neither is graph $(4).$

   To be clear: **all three models, even the purple and red (the theoretical prediction), indicate that percentage protection suffers diminishing returns as sunscreen amount increases**. Beer's Law has ***not*** actually failed. The blue model, which is the most optimistic relative to the theoretical prediction, in fact appears to be [the least well-supported by studies](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?&q=sunscreen+spf+amount).
5. > > The amount used in the sunscreen studies to determine SPF is $2$ milligrams of sunscreen per centimetre of skin. On average, **people apply only a quarter to a half of the recommended amount**

   Therefore, it would be a boon to public health to replace SPF on sunscreens with a measure that is *more realistic* (about the typical amount of sunscreen applied) and also *more intuitive*: say, **sun protection index B**, defined as $$\text{SPI}_B=100\left(1-\frac1{\sqrt{\text{SPF}}}\right).$$ This index, which is basically formula $(4)$ with $x=\dfrac12,$ **varies between $0$ and $100,$ proportionally to the amount of erythemal radiation that the sunscreen filters out** *when the user applies $1$ mg/cm² instead of the unrealistic $2$ mg/cm²*.

   Note that, by definition (‘erythemal dose’), both SPF and SPI$_B$ are heavily biased towards measuring UVB screening.

   So, just as PPD ([persistent pigment darkening](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?&q=ppd+persistent+pigment+darkening)) is the UVA counterpart of SPF, we might analogously define **sun protection index A** (SPI$_A)$ as SPI$_B$'s counterpart for measuring UVA screening (more accurately, for measuring the screening of pigment-darkening radiation): $$\text{SPI}_A=100\left(1-\frac1{\sqrt{\text{PPD}}}\right).$$ This index—analogously to the above index—specifies **the percentage of the pigment-darkening radiation that the sunscreen filters out** *when the user applies $1$ mg/cm² instead of the unrealistic $2$ mg/cm²*.

   As an illustration, the $$\text{PPD } 46,\:\:\text{SPF } 50+$$ rating of [this sunscreen](https://incidecoder.com/products/la-roche-posay-invisible-fluid) is equivalent to $$\text{SPI}_A\:85,\:\:\text{SPI}_B\:86+.$$ NB: many countries forbid sunscreens from being labelled with an SPF above $50,$ due to the prevalent temptation to interpret SPF proportionally to level of protection; since my proposed ratings SPI$_A$ and SPI$_B$ are to be read precisely this way, the “SPF $50+$” above will in fact actually revert to the more precise/informative “SPI$_B$ $91$” (say) instead of being converted to “SPI$_B$ $86+$”.